# I want to add pagination in WordPress using PHP. But I don't know how to do that in a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey I add this code into a WordPress page, this plugin fetch all posts of a specific category, its working fine , I want to add pagination on this code, but I don't know how to do.

```
<?php
 $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=124&posts_per_page=10' );
 while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post()?><div class="main-box">

<div class="photos">
    <ul class="photo-data">
               <li><?php  the_post_thumbnail();  ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="title_desc">


<ul>
     <li style="list-style-type: none;">
          <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
              <?php  $content = get_the_content();
              echo substr($content, 0, 50);  ?>

           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">...Read More</a>
     </li>
</ul>


</div></div><?php endwhile; ?>`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=7&posts_per_page=5&paged='.$paged);
        global $wp_query;
        $tmp_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = $catquery;
        while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post()?>
        <div class="main-box">
            <div class="photos">
                <ul class="photo-data">
                    <li>
                        <?php  the_post_thumbnail();  ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="title_desc">
                <ul>
                    <li style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a></h3>
                        <?php  $content = get_the_content();
                        echo substr($content, 0, 50);  ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">...Read More</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="pagination">
          <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
          <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hey iPraxa LLC thank you for your response but your did not worked.

Comment: Hi Manish Panchal, i have updated the code. Please check with this, it is working fine for me.